# Importing files using PyQGIS on Mac OS

Tags: pyqgis, mac

I have a strong issues to identify the path I must specify to import (or save) a file in PyQGIS.

Here are the different paths given by `sys.path` :

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

#results 

['/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python',
 '/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',
 '/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj-2.6.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
  '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio-1.1.5-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snuggs-1.4.7-py3.8.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/GDAL-3.2.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netCDF4-1.5.4-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/patsy-0.5.1-py3.8.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas-0.8.1-py3.8.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.5.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.20.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cftime-1.2.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels-0.11.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/affine-2.3.0-py3.8.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Rtree-0.9.4-py3.8.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-7.2.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.13.post1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click_plugins-1.1.1-py3.8.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_contrib_python-4.3.0.36-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
 '/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba-0.50.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg',
  '/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',
 '.',
 '/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms']
```

And let say I would like to import a shapefile (or csv if it is easier) named "P1" located in the given directory :
/Users/Me/Documents/Expertise

How should I proceed and, if it is not possible to access the directory, where should my files be located?

Comment: I think you are confusing the python path `sys.path` which is where python looks for python modules and packages with opening/saving a dataset . Look at `QgsVectorLayer('/Users/Me/Documents/Expertise/P1.shp')`  https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @user2856, I can now import a shapefile with the following code from [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html) :

```
import os # This is is needed in the pyqgis console also
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer
)
#get the path to the shapefile e.g. /home/project/data/ports.shp
path_to_layer = "/Volumes/Macbook Me/Users/Me/Downloads/Cluster1/P1.shp"

# The format is:
# vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, layer_name, provider_name)

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_layer, "P1", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Both path "/Volumes/Macbook Me/Users/Me/Downloads/Cluster1/P1.shp" and "/Users/Me/Downloads/Cluster1/P1.shp" work.